# Can you wrap up a single humanoid with a web spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I'm pretty sure of what the answer is, but during combat I had a [drider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/drider) attack my PCs and it used [web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web) on one of them. After careful reading of the spell I'm forced to conclude that I've horribly misused it as I had it wrap up a single player who was out in the open, with nothing for it to anchor to, except himself.

I read [How exactly does the Web spell work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31890/how-exactly-does-the-web-spell-work) and it covers many aspects, but doesn't cover whether web works on a singular creature. Is it reasonable to consider arms to each other or the torso, and legs as being "diametrically opposed points"?

For the people editing my post, the drider used the SPELL and not the ability. So please reflect that its the spell, and not the drider ability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes and no.**

There are two different things called "Web" in Pathfinder: the web *ability* and the web *spell*.

If you're casting the *web* spell, you can't target a single creature.  As the spell description states:

> These masses must be anchored to two or more solid and diametrically opposed points or else the web collapses upon itself and disappears.

Web is an area effect spell, not something that can be targeted at a single creature.  It doesn't work at all unless you have at least two anchor points.  It doesn't just collapse without anchors, it collapses *and disappears*, meaning that the spell stops taking effect immediately without anchors.

However!  Most creatures that can web things don't actually cast the spell, they use the [Web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Web-Ex-) special attack, which is different.  The special attack can be used to make sheets of webbing, or to ensnare individual creatures, like a net would.

You should probably check whether the creature that you used has web as a spell-like ability, or a special attack.  The spell-like ability can't entrap one creature, but the special ability can.

In a few cases, like the [Drider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/drider), the creature has both.  In a case like this, make sure you're using the right kind of Web for your particular situation, since they are used very differently.

Comment: this is the right answer I think, but I would make the fact that there is a difference between the "web" ability and the spell "web" right at the start as that is the point here.

Comment: Actually, the creature had both. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/drider