# How does layering a Web Spell work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

**[*Web*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web) says:**

> If the webs aren't anchored between two solid masses (such as walls or trees) **OR layered across a floor, wall, or ceiling,** the conjured web collapses on itself, and the spell ends at the start of your next turn. Webs layered over a flat surface have a depth of 5 feet.

(emphasis mine)

I'm having difficulty imagining webs not attached to something. Are they stacked up like pancakes? Does this mean I can just throw webs on the ground and not worry about attaching them to something? What are the disadvantages/advantages of anchoring/not anchoring? Or should the "or" in web be an and?

The question "[How exactly does the Web spell work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31890/how-exactly-does-the-web-spell-work)" is similar, but I'm asking about D&D 5th edition, not Pathfinder. The wording is very different.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of spiders who spin their webs across a flat surface. The benefits of anchoring is that you get vertical clearance, or a horizontal bridge across a gap. Layering on the ground makes it a sticky mess. Both have their uses.

Answer (score 5):

**Are they stacked up like pancakes?**

Let's see, they're fluffy, round, delicious, full of air pockets. Yeah, they're pretty much exactly like a pancake, except for the fact that it's 20' wide.

**Does this mean I can just throw webs on the ground and not worry about attaching them to something?**

Yup, they're just attaching to the ground in that case.

**What are the disadvantages/advantages of anchoring/not anchoring?**

The advantages and disadvantages of each are numerous, but can basically be boiled down to *how much of the battlefield do you want obstructed?*

**Should the *or* in web be an *and*?**

No, the spells function is correct as written.

Comment: "Let's see, they're fluffy, round, **delicious**, full of air pockets." I don't know what webs you've been eating...

Comment: @TheLittlePeace The same ones everyone else eats, I would expect.